# How to do remote execution in standard perl 5.10.0

Tags: perl, telnet

I want to run some commands via a remote program. I've tried it using following code.

```
my $promt = '/bash\$ $/';    
use Net::Telnet ();

$conn = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => 10, Prompt => $promt);
$conn->open($host);
$conn->login($username, $passwd);
@lines = $conn->cmd("who");
print @lines;
```

But it gives error,
Can't locate Net/Telnet.pm in @INC.....

Is there way to do this task without changing, adding standard perl 5.10.0 modules?

Comment: Why not just install Net::Telnet? (Please don't reply by saying you don't have root access - you don't need it. Read perlmodinstall for details of installing your own private copy of a module.)

Comment: Is that Net::Telnet package is a default package in Perl??? At least  in the latest versions??? Adding package manually is not a solution since varies users will use this remote program to access source program. Is there way to automate package installing if it is not available???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive solved the problem using this function...

```
# Get the needed values from the database
sub Execute_Remote_Command($) {
    print "sshpass -p $password ssh $user\@$host '$_[0]'\n";
    print `sshpass -p $password ssh $user\@$host '$_[0]'`;
    print `exit`;
}
```

Function -Execute_Remote_Command- needed a parameter which needed to be run in the remote machine.

The only additional requirement needed here is supporting sshpass command and it can be downloaded using following url.
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Security/Sshpass-8693.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Just install the Net::Telnet perl module in your own user path. OR if you are not bound to perl, the best way i can suggest to run commands on remote systems is SSH.

```
$ssh user@ip 'command'
```

This will give you the results in STDOUT.

Examples:

```
root@www:~ # ssh root@www 'who'
brock pts/0 Oct 21 10:31 (75.72.194.149)
jim pts/1 Oct 25 06:25 (128.101.163.128)
```

You can find few more at "[Run Remote Command with SSH](http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html)".